# link with anchor to element in another page

Tags: html, anchor

Back with another big question:

I have to create a network of pages with content linked though them. For link inside the same page i'm using this method:

```
<div id="anchorname">
The content.
</div>
```

and:

```
<a href="#anchorname">Link Text</a>
```

Now i have to link to the #anchorname from another page but it doesn't work, i tried this:

```
<a href="/pagename#anchorname">Link Text</a>
```

Is there something i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This is possible to do. You might try using the full name of the page including the suffix. e.g:

```
<a href="/pagename.html#anchorname">Link Text</a>
```

If that doesn't work then I would experiment with using a full path.

EDIT: As you've stated that you're using Wordpress then you should try it like this:

```
<a href="/pagename/#anchorname">Link Text</a>
```

Comment: i'm in wordpress so there is no .html here. i tried also the full path includin http:// but it doesn't work. i only get at the top of the page.

Comment: In that case I believe you need to put the unique identifier after a forward slash. I've update my answer to show you.

Comment: ok i tried your new answer but no change in result. Keep going to the page but does not scroll down to the id.

Comment: Double check that you have spelt the id the same - remember it is case sensitive.

Comment: nothing.... i don't know why but i doesn't work for me.... any othe ruggestions or methods for doing the same thing?

Comment: I can refer you to this article from Wordpress support which might help further: https://en.support.wordpress.com/splitting-content/page-jumps/